# Error handle: Element name is not valid?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I am trying to insert bulk JSON string document in MongoDB. but some of the document is like in below JSON format.

```
{
  "application.data":"process"
}
```

Here Problem is showing error message: `Element name "application.data" is not valid`.

current code base

```
var collectionData = dataBase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collectionName");
string json = "{ "application.data":"process" }";

var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);//here is throwing error

collectionData?.InsertOne(document);
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question...

Comment: Can you post how json is being initialized? Otherwise, its undefined and the deserializer will throw an error for attempting to deserialize an undefined variable.

Comment: json in string format 

string json = "{ "application.data":"process" }";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string json = "{ "application.data":"process" }";
```

is not a valid JSON string. The second double quotes is closing the string and there is no concatenation operator that is followed up. If you need double quotes for application.data and process (I'm guessing you do), use the backslash delimiter.

```
var jsonString = JSON.parse("{ \"application.data\":\"process\" }");
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 4):

Even though the mongodb allows this in the database engine and the mongo shell:

```
> db.test.insert( { "text.this" : true } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f2095e1bd0eaac6294dcf"), "text.this" : true }
>
```

I'd strongly advise against it as querying will be a nightmare.

However, if you've got a JSON string in C# I'd use something like Json.NET and split out the `.` into an embedded document:

```
string json = "{ \"application.data\":\"process\" }";
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

var jWithDot = jObject.Properties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(".")).ToList();
foreach (var j in jWithDot)
{
    var names = j.Name.Split(".");

    var jProperty = new JProperty(names[0], new JObject(new JProperty(names[1], j.Value)));
    j.Replace(jProperty);
}

// { "application": { "data": "process" } }
var newJson = jObject.ToString();
```

Then you can splat that in MongoDB like normal

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient();
var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

collection.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse(newJson));
```

After execution you'll see the following in the shell:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0f236605267300e0911e43"), "application" : { "data" : "process" } }
```

Comment: this code is working if the invalid property name is only in the root object. but in case any invalid property comes in children object or array list then this need to change

Comment: Convert all the child documents too then? 